# Why does Tohru always try to get Kobayashi to eat pieces of her tail?

Tags: miss-kobayashis-dragon-maid

In [Kobayashi-san Chi no Maid Dragon](https://myanimelist.net/anime/33206/Kobayashi-san_Chi_no_Maid_Dragon), Tohru always tries to get Kobayashi to eat pieces of her tail. Why?  This started in episode 1 and has carried through to the current episode, with a mention/attempt almost every episode.

Is this a sign of affection for dragons?

Comment: Does it have to be anything else than [Running Gag](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RunningGag)?

Comment: It seems to be a running gag for sure, but I think there is a deeper meaning somewhere. I figured it had a meaning at the start and then turned into a running gag.

Comment: Possibly related: [Would eating Tooru's tail make Kobayashi immortal?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/57987/2516)

Answer (score 12):

While it hasn't been explicitly stated in the show, I think the biggest factor is that it's an extremely *intimate* thing to do. It might be a bit disgusting when put this way, but a lot of intimate acts amongst humans involve the mingling or exchanging of bodily fluids; and that extends to the deal with vampires drinking blood - it's a precious bodily fluid, and there is something quite intense about giving it to someone. So for Tohru, who can apparently regrow her tail pretty quickly, having Kobayashi eat the meat is having her master take a part of her and ingest it, which in her eyes is an incredibly special form of bonding.

Answer (score 6):

Well, having just watched the series, I think they have the right of it, in that Tohru hopes that by having Miss Kobayashi *eat her tail*, she will gain her power, thus allowing her to keep their little family together.

Not only is there the concept in parts of Asia and most early tribal civilizations of *eating mythical beasts to gain their power...* but then there it the **Ouroboros myth, the dragon eating it's own tail representing eternity.**

I think it's also **very** likely, given Tohru's feelings for Miss Kobayashi, and also knowing that her sexual advances have been rebuffed so far, that it also would represent a kind of physical bond between them, a way for a little part of her to be *inside* Miss Kobayashi, and therefore have some bit of intimacy through that.

In summary, I believe the reason is twofold: a combination of a **desire for a physical bond between them** and a way to **share her immortal lifespan with her** so try to be together, if not *forever*, then for a long, long time to come.

It's a bit odd from a human perspective, but in Tohru's mind it would be a bit romantic. Like a mate that kept a lock of your hair in a locket around their neck all the time so they'd always have a piece of you with them.

*grin*

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's both a form of deep affection, as well as Tohru attempting to indefinitely extend Kobayashi's lifespan.

The consumption of the flesh of dragons myth doesn't just span only to Eastern myth. And to note, Leviathan, Elma, and Fafnir are in fact Eastern orientation dragons (to be specific, Northeastern).

It's long been believed that dragon flesh and blood have magical and enhancing abilities.